# VALARMs from iCalendars (.ics) not being recognized by Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

Google Calendar is not recognizing VALARMs from .ics files when importing. Consider the calendar below with one event and a reminder. Everything imports fine except for the reminder email - (specified by the VALARM section), which is ignored by the import.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:Recurring

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160408T231500
SUMMARY:Groceries
DESCRIPTION:Get food
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:EMAIL
DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder
SUMMARY:Alarm notification
ATTENDEE:mailto:foo@example.com
TRIGGER:-P0DT0H30M0S
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

Was it fixing newline characters? No.

Was it adding a UID? No.

Was it adding a DTSTART attribute? No.

The same `.ics` file must be imported **twice** before Google Calendar will honor the `VALARM` notifiers.

Event details will be imported on the first import. The second import will import the alarms. Ugh...

Sorry about the [tinge of frustration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QvhCDsFkk0). It was by dumb luck I found the solution buried in an [obscure reply](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/calendar/PiOJn4HOJwI/GSsbei-gDAAJ) on one of the Google Calendar forum threads.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the trick was to enable notifications on the specific calender first.

So the steps are the following:

1. Create/Edit the calendar you want to add/import events from `.ics` file to
2. Enable notifications for event notifications (both, for normal events and daily event)
3. Import the `.ics` file to the configured calendar

Note: the exact order of the steps is neccessary