# Is .ics file VALARM section works with Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have an ics file that has several events and I want to make all subscribers of this calendar to receive notification about the event 10 minutes before the event in Google calendar. Is it possible with VALARM or I need to create a separate calendar with settings via Google API?

I defined two VALARM sections in my .ics file but Google calendar doesn't send me any email or browser notifications anyway:

```
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder
END:VALARM
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:EMAIL
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to force on your subscribers.  If you look at similar possibly duplicate questions, it may be possible for users to get notifications on your events IF

1. They switch notifications on for the subscribed calendar themselves after subscribing in google calender
   OR
2. the events are imported (not subscribed) AND
3. the user has notifications switched on in their destination calendar by default.

See also

- [Sent email with iCal to outlook with valarm reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256584/sent-email-with-ical-to-outlook-with-valarm-reminder/33268200#33268200)
- [Given ics VALARM properies are not appearing in Google Calendar or Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398917/given-ics-valarm-properies-are-not-appearing-in-google-calendar-or-outlook)
- [VALARMs from iCalendars (.ics) not being recognized by Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863320/valarms-from-icalendars-ics-not-being-recognized-by-google-calendar)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did you ever used [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview)? Maybe it's possible to define default notification params for calendar created by my app and then provide a subscription link to end users? I actually want to create calendar feed with predifined notification settings at least for Google calendar

Comment: I created separate calendar and shared it with my second Google account, so notifications weren't be imported, they appeared only when I import this calendar as my own. Looks like you're totally right, thanks.